# Grammaticalité de « que/dont on n'aurait jamais attendu connaître »

Tags: grammaire, vocabulaire, pronoms-relatifs

J'hésite sur la grammaticalité des phrases suivantes...

*Un peu de contexte : on parle d'objets anciens en remarquant qu'il est incroyable que ces derniers aient pu être conservés jusqu'à aujourd'hui*

> Le musée héberge toutes sortes de choses **que l'on n'aurait jamais
>   attendu connaître**...
>
> Le musée héberge toutes sortes de choses **dont on n'aurait jamais
>   attendu connaître**...

Dans un deuxième temps, je voulais savoir si l'emploi de "connaître" est déplacé/erroné, compte tenu du contexte.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Connaître** : oui on peut l'employer et l'emploi est correct. Mais dans le contexte d'objets anciens dans un musée, « découvrir » pourrait aussi être employé.

Par contre, en ce qui concerne encore le vocabulaire, il y a une confusion entre « attendre » et « s'attendre à ».

- **Attendre** (quelqu'un ou quelque chose) :

  - J'irai t'attendre à l'arrivée du train.
- **S'attendre à** (quelque chose, peut être suivi d'un nom ou d'un verbe), verbe pronominal :

  - On s'attend à une remontée des températures en fin de semaine.
  - On peut s'attendre à ce qu'il fasse chaud en fin de semaine.

(La construction de « s'attendre à » [donne lieu à des controverses](http://alafortunedumot.blogs.lavoixdunord.fr/tag/s%27attendre+%C3%A0+ce+que)  et pourrait au besoin faire l'objet d'une autre question).

Dans ta phrase il faut utiliser « **s'attendre à** » :

> Le musée héberge toutes sortes de choses qu'on ne se serait jamais attendu à connaître/découvrir.

Avec « dont » la construction n'est pas possible, sauf à utiliser une structure différente, comme par exemple, et pour rester au plus proche de ta proposition :

> Le musée héberge toutes sortes de choses dont on n'aurait jamais cru pouvoir faire la découverte.

---

Si tu comprends l'anglais, « attendre » c'est *to wait* (*for*). « S'attendre à » c'est *to expect*.

Answer (score -3):

**I**

La première phrases n'est  pas grammaticale, mais seulement dans une partie de la construction verbale : « attendre » n'est pas construit sans  une préposition. On pourrait donc écrire avec les phrases avec « attendu de connaitre » au lieu de « attendu connaitre » et elle serait alors correcte grammaticalement ; cependant, le sens n'est pas clair parce qu'il n'existe aucun contexte évident qui indique qu'il faille attendre en vue de pouvoir connaitre, pas dans le domaine des objets anciens dans le contexte le plus général. Cela peut être vrai dans un contexte bien défini, comme par exemple dans le domaine de l'apprentissage.

- Le professeur dissimulait des questions que l'on n'aurait jamais attendu de connaitre et que l'on aurait élucidées tout de suite ; il faisait cela selon un principe pédagogique dans lequel il croyait.

Il faut donc déterminer ce que l'on veut dire et remplacer « attendre de connaitre » ou un des verbes dans la construction « attendu de connaitre » par un autre verbe de sorte à donner le sens voulu à la phrase. Des formes verbales  évidentes parmi un grand nombre sont « espéré  connaitre »  et  « soupçonné d'exister ».

- Le musée héberge toutes sortes de choses **que** l'on n'aurait jamais **espéré connaître**...

**II**

La seconde phrase a le même problème et en plus elle comporte une anomalie en cela que « dont » appelle un verbe qui se construit avec « de », ce qui n'est pas le cas de « connaitre ».

- parler **de** qqc : la maison **dont** il parle au bord de la mer
- se souvenir **de** qqc : les enfants **dont** il se souvient dans les classes passées
- discuter de qqc : les sujets **dont** nous discutions

…

Plusieurs construction verbales pourront rendre un sens à la phrase : « espéré entendre parler », « pu discuter », etc.

- Le musée héberge toute sortes de choses **dont** on n'aurait jamais **espéré entendre parler**...

Comment: Pour moi cet emploi d'attendre n'est tout simplement pas possible. « Le professeur dissimulait des questions que l'on n'aurait jamais attendu de connaitre.. » n'est tout simplement français. Il faut l'emploi pronominal du verbe dans cette phrase.

Comment: @Laure Je ne crois pas qu'il y ait un tour non idiomatique ; ce n'est peut-être pas une combinaison descriptive d'un contexte courant et en cela elle serait inhabituelle à l'oreille. ex. Je n'ai pas attendu de connaitre la théorie pour m'intéresser à ce point particulier. • Ils ont attendu de connaitre les grottes  à fond avant de s'y aventurer sans guide. • On n'aurait jamais attendu de connaitre les grottes à fond avant de s'y aventurer seuls si un guide ne nous avait pas avertis.■ Qu'est-ce que vous en pensez maintenant ?

Comment: J'aurait tendance a alléger votre réponse. C'est bien de donner un contexte technique, mais pour quelqu'un qui veut apprendre je trouve votre réponse lourde a lire. Peut-etre donner des examples au début ? et finir par le coté technique ?

Comment: @yagmoth555 Je sais bien que celui qui explique n'est pas à la place de celui qui reçoit l'explication, mais je sais aussi qu'il n'y a pas de réponse facile à une question difficile.